# Best caching principle to store form based application data

Tags: java, design-patterns

My application have around 30  page which then creates account after pushing submit button on the last page. Currently the application is submitting the data of each page into database when next button is pressed for navigation to the next page and when previous button is pressed again the data is retrieved from database and displayed in the previous page.
Basically throughout my navigation I should be aware of data of all the previous form in some cache

This all seems to be taking too much time as number of database transaction .I want to keep all the data into memory until the submit button is pressed on the last page .i was thinking of creating a hashmap object which will hold all the data and when submit button is pressed on the last page pull all the hashmap data and store in the database.

Could anybody suggest any better design principle which will solve my purpose.

Comment: How do you know the database transactions are the bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that the number of database transactions is the root cause of the low performance of your app. I suspect there must be some unwanted overhead with either in the communication between the client and server, or somewhere else.

By keeping all the 30 pages in memory you mean in the server memory or in the client memory? Actually, write a test to keep the data in the server memory  (without storing to database) and you will compare the speed. That's the only way how you find where your bottleneck is.

Anyway, still I have some doubts about the design of your application if you need 30 (thirty) pages before you are able to commit the final data... It's like a 30-lines-long sentence with a lot of inserted clauses without a fullstop - such a text is usually unreadable.